# Apache Beam Python: returning conditional statement using ParDo class

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I want to check, if the CSV file we read in the pipeline of apache beam, satisfies the format I'm expecting it to be in [Ex: field check, type check, null value check, etc.], before performing any transformation.

Performing these checks outside the pipeline for every file will take away the concept of parallelism, so I just wanted to know if it was possible to perform it inside the pipeline.

An example of what the code might look like:

```
import apache_beam as beam

branched=beam.Pipeline()

class f_c(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        if element == feld:
            return True
        else:
            return False

input_collection = ( 
branched 
    | 'Read from text file' >> beam.io.ReadFromText("gs://***.csv")
    | 'Split rows' >> beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(',')))

field_check=(input_collection
    | 'field function returning True or False' >> beam.ParDo(f_c())
    | beam.io.WriteToText('gs://***/op'))

branched.run().wait_unitl_finish
```

Comment: A couple of clarifications: 1. Do you wish to reject/discard the rows that don't meet a certain requirement or write them into a different path?  2.  Are further transformations going to happen within the pipeline itself?

Comment: Hey Saransh,
I wish to write the files into different folders as of now, based on the checks performed, the two folders are op-validated and op-failed and I'm not changing anything in the input file, just redirecting it to respective paths.
As of now, I'm trying to segregate the files, the transformation is done using another pipeline, using a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated a small instance of the problem with with just two rules.
if the length of 3th column is >10 and value of 4th column is >500 then that record is good else its a bad record.

```py
    from apache_beam.io.textio import WriteToText
    import apache_beam as beam
    
    class FilterFn(beam.DoFn):
      """
      The rules I have assumed is to just perform a length check on the third column and 
      value check on forth column
      if(length of 3th column) >10 and (value of 4th column) is >500 then that record is good
      """
      def process(self, text):
    #------------------ -----isGoodRow BEGINS-------------------------------
        def isGoodRow(a_list):
          if( (len(a_list[2]) > 10) and (int(a_list[3]) >100) ):
            return True
          else:
            return False
    #------------------- ----isGoodRow ENDS-------------------------------
        a_list = []
        a_list = text.split(",") # this list contains all the column for a periticuar i/p Line
        bool_result = isGoodRow(a_list)
        if(bool_result == True):
          yield beam.TaggedOutput('good', text)
        else:
          yield beam.TaggedOutput('bad', text)
    
    with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
      split_me = (
          pipeline
          | 'Read from text file' >> beam.io.ReadFromText("/content/sample.txt")
          | 'Split words and Remove N/A' >> beam.ParDo(FilterFn()).with_outputs('good','bad')
          )
      good_collection = (
          split_me.good 
          |"write good o/p" >> beam.io.WriteToText(file_path_prefix='/content/good',file_name_suffix='.txt')
          ) 
      bad_collection = (
          split_me.bad 
          |"write bad o/p" >> beam.io.WriteToText(file_path_prefix='/content/bad',file_name_suffix='.txt')
          )
```

I have written a [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/) `FilterFn` that Tags output based of `isGoodRow` function. You can rewrite the logic with your requirements ex. null checks, data validation etc.
The other option could be to use a [Partition Function](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/partition/) for this use case.

The sample.txt I used for this example:

```
1,Foo,FooBarFooBarFooBar,1000
2,Foo,Bar,10
3,Foo,FooBarFooBarFooBar,900
4,Foo,FooBar,800
```

Output of good.txt

```
1,Foo,FooBarFooBarFooBar,1000
3,Foo,FooBarFooBarFooBar,900
```

Output of bad.txt

```
2,Foo,Bar,10
4,Foo,FooBar,800
```

Comment: Hey Saransh, is there a way to write whole file into good or bad, instead of particular rows? That is, if we get one bad row, we write the whole file into '/content/bad' and if all rows are good, then into '/content/good'

Comment: for this you can use FileIO to get the file metadata and then read the file file line by line within the ParDo (`funN`). After that based on some condition you can assign the tag to entire file name/metadata. Then again read the tagged file and write them onto the final target based on the tag. the only limitation with this is it'll be slow if your file is very large in size.